# Example of a prime ideal that is not a kernel

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

Does anyone know of a prime ideal $I \subseteq R := K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ of a polynomial ring such that for any other polynomial ring $S = K[y_1, \dots, y_m]$ and ring map $\phi : R \rightarrow S$, we have $\ker(\phi) \neq I$.

I'm mostly interested in polynomial rings over $\mathbb C$. If $R = \mathbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $I$ is prime and generated by binomials then $I$ is toric, so it is the kernel of a monomial map.

I'm not sure if this would be easier from a geometric viewpoint; I'm asking something like: does there exists an irreducible affine variety that does not admit a (rational?) parametrisation.

Comment: I don't understand the question: *any* ideal of *any* ring (commutative or not) is the kernel of $R \to R/I$.

Comment: You're right, I'll focus on the case I'm interested in

Comment: The answer to your geometric question is yes: a smooth affine cubic curve such as $y^2 = x^3 - x$ is an irreducible affine variety that admits no rational parametrization. In fact any smooth affine plane curve of degree $d \ge 3$ is irrational.

Comment: Curves of positive genus do not admit a rational parametrization.